# How to update first x number of documents in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to update first x number of documents in mongoose
I know how to update multiple documents based on a condition. but I want to update first 5 documents in mongoose

I know I can do something like this

```
users =await Stock.find({city : 'surat'}).select(id).limit(5);
await Stock.updateMany({id : {'$in' : users},city : 'mumbai'})
```

but is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort or limit with updating documents. There is no better way of doing that.